# How to get the Value of a Domain attribute with Master Data Services (MDS) WCF API

Tags: c#, wcf, master-data-services, mds

To get the grips of the MDS WCF API I started a .Net Core console application. I'm struggling to find detailed documentation on the data structure used in the API.
I now have a simple function that uses **EntityMembersGet** to read the Members (rows) of a certain Entity.
Data is returned by the MDS Service but when I try to read/display the data I can't figure out how to display the Value of a Domain attribute. To display the values of the attributes I use **EntityMembers.Members.Attributes[].Value** which works perfectly when the Attribute is a Freefrom attribute. However, when the Attribute is a Domain attribute the use of EntityMembers.Members.Attributes[].Value returns "MDService.MemberIdentifier".
So, my question is, how can I get the Value of a Domain attribute?

I have shared my code and the output.

As a secondary question, it would be great if someone can point me to a more descriptive documentation of the MDS WCF API than what is on MSDN.

```
 public static async Task ReadRecordsAsync()
    {
        EntityMembersGetRequest getRequest = new EntityMembersGetRequest();
        EntityMembersGetResponse getResponse = new EntityMembersGetResponse();

        EntityMembersGetCriteria membersGetCriteria = new EntityMembersGetCriteria
        {
            ModelId = new Identifier() { Name = "Model1" },
            EntityId = new Identifier() { Name = "Entity1" },
            VersionId = new Identifier() { Name = "VERSION_1" },
            MemberType = MemberType.Leaf,
            MemberReturnOption = MemberReturnOption.DataAndCounts
        };

        getRequest.MembersGetCriteria = membersGetCriteria;
        //EntityMembersGetResponse getResponse = await mdsProxy.EntityMembersGetAsync(getRequest);
        getResponse = await mdsProxy.EntityMembersGetAsync(getRequest);

        Console.WriteLine("Member information: \n Membercount: {0} | TotalPages: {1}", getResponse.EntityMembersInformation.MemberCount, getResponse.EntityMembersInformation.TotalPages);
        //Console.WriteLine("Members: \n Count: {0}", getResponse.EntityMembers.Members.Count.ToString());

        if (getResponse.EntityMembers.Members.Count > 0)
        {              
            foreach (Member individualMember in getResponse.EntityMembers.Members)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----------");
                Console.WriteLine("Individual Member: \n Id: {0} | Code: {1} | Name: {2}",
                    individualMember.MemberId.Id, 
                    individualMember.MemberId.Code,
                    individualMember.MemberId.Name);
                for (int i = 0; i < individualMember.Attributes.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Attributes ({0}): \n Id Id: {1} | Id name: {2} | Type: {3} | Value: {4} \n ",
                        i,
                        individualMember.Attributes[i].Identifier.Id,
                        individualMember.Attributes[i].Identifier.Name,
                        individualMember.Attributes[i].Type,
                        individualMember.Attributes[i].Value
                        );
                    if (individualMember.Attributes[i].Type == AttributeValueType.Domain)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Domain attribute");
                    }
                }
            }
```

The output when running the application: see at end of line of "Attributes (2)" for the Domain attribute output.

```
Member information:
 Membercount: 3 | TotalPages: 1
----------
Individual Member:
 Id: 655b4f56-8a03-47cc-bbdd-311d0103a97e | Code: Code1 | Name: Naam1
Attributes (0):
 Id Id: bc2a8c6d-bf50-41b5-bef5-4170949ec93c | Id name: No. | Type: String | Value: No.1

Attributes (1):
 Id Id: bb71e279-74ce-4131-a56a-f7be884d6067 | Id name: Description | Type: String | Value: Desc1

Attributes (2):
 Id Id: 5db1b524-c2ec-47ff-8d74-399859c6fed0 | Id name: UnitOfMeasure | Type: Domain | Value: MDService.MemberIdentifier

Domain attribute
----------
Individual Member:
 Id: d3fc1b10-30ee-4546-9b75-5c9c89c3fd00 | Code: Code2 | Name: Naam2
Attributes (0):
 Id Id: bc2a8c6d-bf50-41b5-bef5-4170949ec93c | Id name: No. | Type: String | Value: No.2

Attributes (1):
 Id Id: bb71e279-74ce-4131-a56a-f7be884d6067 | Id name: Description | Type: String | Value: Desc2

Attributes (2):
 Id Id: 5db1b524-c2ec-47ff-8d74-399859c6fed0 | Id name: UnitOfMeasure | Type: Domain | Value: MDService.MemberIdentifier

Domain attribute
----------
```

Answer (score 0):

Going through the Feature samples of SQL on GitHub I found the answer to my question.
When the attribute is a Domain attribute you can use the MemberIdentifier class to get the properties of the attribute:

```
if (Attribute.Type == AttributeValueType.Domain)
{
   MemberIdentifier dbaMemberId = (MemberIdentifier)anAttribute.Value;
   Console.WriteLine("Attribute Value:{0}", dbaMemberId.Code);
}
```

I hope this helps someone else looking for this type of info.

*edit*: this is the link to the samples on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sql-database-samples)